# How do you style iOS UIElements in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I am absolutely dumbfounded on the concept of styling elements in Swift. I'm very used to HTML/CSS so forgive me if I'm not using the correct terminology. I'm used to being able to say `thisElement` has the style

`width: 50%;
height: 100px;
background-color: #ff00ff;`

What would be the equivalent. Be aware I'm very new to all of this.

Answer (score 2):

The closest you can get is something called the *appearance proxy*. This basically lets you set common features of all widgets of a common type, and is usually called as the app starts up.

Also, though, keep in mind that you're working here with an object-oriented universe. So if you really did have, say, a button that always needed to be 100 by 50 in size and appears in many places in the app, you would subclass UIButton and have your subclass configure itself to be that size - and then use that subclass wherever you wanted a button that looked like that.

Comment: See, on the appearance proxy, the discussion in my book: http://www.apeth.com/iOSBook/ch25.html#_appearance_proxy

Comment: Oh, and there's a very good WWDC video on the subject of thematizing your app's appearance, from two or three years ago, IIRC.